# What is the best approach database structure for teacher, students and address table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I have the following tables in my database

- students
- teachers
- address

I Want to store basic information about students and teacher in its own table, but the address and contact information in address table. If I store the `student_id` or `teacher_id` in address table, the student might have same `id` as any teacher. If I try to query any teacher address by `teacher_id`. It will query the student who has the same `id` as well.

So what the best way to figure out this problem? should I create any other table as well or ....

Please suggest me an easiest and best approach.

thanks.

Comment: You may add another field in address table like 'is_student' which will denote whose address is this.

Comment: there must be a better way. I am looking for that :(

Comment: is it allowed to have multiple address of a single teacher/student in your case?

Comment: if you need to store only general information of student and teacher than you use one common table for both student and teacher so you have always unique id to use in address table also you add address in same table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see th above example. i think best way for solving your problem.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I was thing in reverse others :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the best approach is you have to create a new table called `Users`. See the bellow tables,

**1. Users**

```
id 
user_type (student/teacher) 
name
```

**2. Teachers**

```
id
user_id (fk - users)
address_id (fk - address)
subject
hours
```

**3. Students**

```
id
user_id (fk - users)
address_id (fk - address)
mark
```

**4. Address**

```
id
address1
address2
```

This way a student or a teacher can refer their address.

Comment: thank you, I was thinking in reverse order, that's why. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to structure your tables `students` and `teachers` with a field `address_id` which should point towards the `id` in `address` table.

Comment: thanks, I got the point